Seeking solution for "ERROR TypeError: Streaming request bodies is not supported, js engine: hermes"
Full error log below.
This is a React-JS app using Expo.
In my App.js file, import 'react-native-polyfill-globals/auto' is the first import... this looks to be the problem! If I "npx expo start" with this import statement, I get the following errors. If I comment it out, the app launches, but other elemennts will not work. The app uses Supabase auth and cloud, PowerSync local-db and syncing. Full package.json details also listed below.
ERROR  TypeError: Streaming request bodies is not supported, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes

  "dependencies": { "@azure/core-asynciterator-polyfill": "^1.0.2", "@journeyapps/react-native-quick-sqlite": "^1.1.7", "@powersync/attachments": "^2.0.10", "@powersync/common": "^1.11.1", "@powersync/react": "^1.3.5", "@powersync/react-native": "^1.7.1", "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1", "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1", "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1", "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11", "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17", "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20", "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.39.2", "axios": "^1.7.2", "base-64": "^1.0.0", "expo": "~51.0.14", "expo-av": "~14.0.5", "expo-build-properties": "^0.12.3", "expo-clipboard": "~6.0.3", "expo-dev-client": "^4.0.18", "expo-file-system": "~17.0.1", "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.5", "expo-media-library": "~16.0.3", "expo-print": "~13.0.1", "expo-router": "^3.5.16", "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1", "expo-sharing": "~12.0.1", "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1", "expo-updates": "~0.25.17", "powersync": "^0.4.1", "react": "18.2.0", "react-native": "0.74.2", "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0", "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.1", "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3", "react-native-fetch-api": "^3.0.0", "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1", "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.11.0", "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0", "react-native-polyfill-globals": "^3.1.0", "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1", "react-native-reanimated-table": "^0.0.2", "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1", "react-native-screens": "3.31.1", "react-native-svg": "15.2.0", "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0", "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3", "react-native-view-shot": "3.8.0", "react-native-webview": "13.8.6", "text-encoding": "^0.7.0", "victory-native": "^36.9.1", "web-streams-polyfill": "^3.2.1" },
I have seen links in GitHub issues related to axios 1.7.2 but that is already in my dependencies.

Additional details from Call Stack... "Streaming request bodies is not supported"
Constructor is node_modules/react-native-fetch-api/src/Request.js
nde_modules/axios/lib/adapters/fetch.js
